# É possível retornar o resultado do Javascript no HTML apenas com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Como posso retornar o resultado desse código no HTML: A função main do código está no final do código...

```
//estrutura do problema.
var problem = {
    init_state:"III",
    end_state:"VIII",
    action: [
        ["I",1,280],["II",2,280],['IV',3,240],["V",4,770],['VI',5,180]
        ,["VIII",6,770],['VII',7,1330],['VII',8,1000],['IX',9,830],['VIII',10,1400]
        ],
    costs:[
        ["I",1,280],["II",1,280],["III",2,230],['III',3,240],["III",8,1000]
        ,["IV",4,770],['IV',6,770],['IV',7,1330],['V',5,180],['VII',10,830],['VII',9,1400]
        ]
}
//Variável que receberá a solução.
var soluction = null;
//Variável que receberá a borda.
var border = [];
//Função para cria o nó.
function createNode(init_state,noFather,action,cost,profundity){
    var node = {
        state:init_state,
        noFather: noFather,
        action:action,
        cost:cost,
        profundity:profundity
    }

    return node;
}
//Função que fará os testes.
function test(problem,node){
    console.log("Testando...\n Atual:",node.state," Objetivo:",problem.end_state," Ação:",node.action);
    if(problem.end_state === node.state){
        soluction = node;
        console.log("Encontramos o objetivo:",soluction);
        return true;
    }else{
       return false 
    }
}
//Função para remover o primeiro da borda.
function removerFisrt(border){
    var no;
    if(border){ 
        no = border[0];
        border.splice(0,1);
    }
    return no;
}
//Função que pegará os nós sucessores.
function successor(no,problem){

    var actions_possibles = [];
    //Procurando as ações possiveis.
    for(var i =0; i < Object.keys(problem.costs).length;i++){
        if(problem.costs[i][0]===no.state){
            actions_possibles.push(problem.costs[i][1]);
        }
    }
    //Procurando os problemas ações.
    var problem_actions = [];
    for(var i=0; i< Object.keys(actions_possibles).length;i++){
        for(var j =0; j <Object.keys(problem.action).length;j++){
            if(problem.action[j][1] === actions_possibles[i]){
                problem_actions.push(problem.action[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return problem_actions;

}
//Função que adicionará os nós sucessores em uma borda.
function addInBorder(border,sucessors){
    for(var i =0;i<Object.keys(sucessors).length;i++){
        border.push(sucessors[i]);
    }
}
//Função para expadir.
function expand(node,problem){
   var sucessors = [];
   var problem_actions = [];
   problem_actions = successor(node,problem);
   for(var i =0; i < Object.keys(problem_actions).length;i++){
        var node = createNode(problem_actions[i][0],node.state,problem_actions[i][1],problem_actions[i][2],node.profundity+1);
        sucessors.push(node);
   }
   return sucessors;
}
//Funçao que busca na árvore.
function searchInTree(problem,border){

    border.push(createNode(problem.init_state,null,null,0,0)); 
    while(soluction === null){
        if(border===null || border === undefined || ''){console.log("Ocorreu uma falha");}
        var node = removerFisrt(border);
        if(test(problem,node)){console.log("Chegamos ao destino:",problem.end_state," pela à ação ", node.action," com o custo de ", node.cost,"."); break}
        addInBorder(border,expand(node,problem));
    }
}
//Funçao princiapl onde o fluxo começa ao receber o evento click.
var main = function(){
    console.log("Objetivo Final:",problem.end_state," \n\n\n");
    searchInTree(problem,border);
}
```

HTML está assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Algoritmo de Busca</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" id="box">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" onclick="javascript:main();" >Começar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="resultado">

    </div>

<script src="algoritmo.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A saída esperada no HTML é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no botão começar, o código exiba na div do HTML a busca do algoritmo.
Isso é possível só com o javascript?

Comment: será que `document.getElementByID('resultado').innerHTML  = "Objetivo Final:" + problem.end_state;` não resolve?

Comment: Ou pode colocar isso numa  `function` e usar no lugar do `console.log`. Se não souber posso fazer um exemplo

Comment: @RicardoPontual mostra aí um exemplo, Valeu !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui um exemplo de função para logar (só trocar o 'console.log' por 'logar'):

```
function logar() {
     // onde vai ser escrito o log
     var logger = document.getElementById('resultado');
     // verifica da parâmetro passaod para a função, separado por vírgula
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        //se for um objeto, serializa para melhorar a visualização e adiciona na div, e depois pula uma linha
        if (typeof arguments[i] == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(arguments[i], undefined, 2) : arguments[i]) + '<br />';
        } else { 
            //senão, simplesmente adiciona na div
            logger.innerHTML += arguments[i] + ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Copiado desse exemplo, que "sobrescreve" a função `console.log` e adiciona comentários: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mGDet/

Comment: Funcionou muito bem!
Obrigado aí. Agora só estou com problemas para pular as linhas, vou ver isso aqui. O mais importante já foi feito. Grato! ;D

Comment: Pular as linhas? Basta por um `br` aqui: `logger.innerHTML += arguments[i] + '<br />'` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pra você imprimir direto no html com javascript pode ser assim:

```
var divR = document.getElementById('resultado');

var p;
var text;

for ( var i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
        p = document.createElement( 'p' );
        text = document.createTextNode( 'par: ' + i  ) ;
        p.append( text );

        divR.appendChild( p );
    }
    else {
        console.log( 'ímpar: ' + i );
    }
}
```

Imprimir pares no HTML e ímpares no console, nesse caso eu estou criando um elemento 'P', preenchendo ele com texto e adicionando como filho na div resultado. Espero que tenha lhe ajudado.